# Connect lookup field to a list inside an app

Tags: sharepoint-online, lookup-column, sharepoint-hosted-app

I have a list in SharePoint online which should get a lookup a field to a list which is inside a SharePoint hosted app / add-in. Is it possible?

My app has "FullControl" rights on the web and on the list from the Host Web

Answer (score 0):

Lookup fields can work only with lists on current Web.